# npm run dev causes errors on fresh laravel 5.6.x installation

Tags: npm-install, laravel-5.6, npm-run

I'm busy learning Laravel and run into a problem when i want to run `npm run dev`

First some background information:

- Laravel version 5.6.22
- npm version 6.01
- node version 8.10.0
- OS Ubuntu 18.4 LTS
- PHP 7.2.5
- Composer v 1.6.3

Executed steps:

1. Created a new laravel project `sudo composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel npmtest`
2. Grant all permissions (i'm aware of the security risks with 777 but did this just to test) `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/npmtest`
3. did a `sudo composer install` in the project root
4. followed by `sudo npm install` (already some error noticed)

Result of `sudo npm install`

```
    npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5

> node-sass@4.9.0 install /var/www/npmtest/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Unable to save binary /var/www/npmtest/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-57 : { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/npmtest/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:885:18)
    at sync (/var/www/npmtest/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
    at Function.sync (/var/www/npmtest/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:77:24)
    at checkAndDownloadBinary (/var/www/npmtest/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:114:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/npmtest/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:157:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  path: '/var/www/npmtest/node_modules/node-sass/vendor' }

> uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall /var/www/npmtest/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
> node lib/post_install.js


> node-sass@4.9.0 postinstall /var/www/npmtest/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: /usr/bin/node /var/www/npmtest/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ '/usr/bin/node',
gyp verb cli   '/var/www/npmtest/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
gyp info using node@8.10.0 | linux | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python2 /usr/bin/python2
gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python2 -c "import platform; print(platform.python_version());"` returned: "2.7.15rc1\n"
gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 8.10.0
gyp verb command install [ '8.10.0' ]
gyp verb install input version string "8.10.0"
gyp verb install installing version: 8.10.0
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
gyp verb install version is good
gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 8.10.0
gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /var/www/npmtest/node_modules/node-sass/build
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/npmtest/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-20-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/var/www/npmtest/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /var/www/npmtest/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v8.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.9.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.9.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/roge/.npm/_logs/2018-05-18T13_53_01_126Z-debug.log
```

As i had no idea what to do with the errors and noticed that some of them go over permissions and permissions of node-modules where not 777, probably because executing `npm install` as root, i did:

5. `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/npmtest` again
6. followed by `sudo npm install` again

Result:

```
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5

> node-sass@4.9.0 install /var/www/npmtest/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Unable to save binary /var/www/npmtest/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-57 : { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/npmtest/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:885:18)
    at sync (/var/www/npmtest/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
    at Function.sync (/var/www/npmtest/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:77:24)
    at checkAndDownloadBinary (/var/www/npmtest/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:114:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/npmtest/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:157:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  path: '/var/www/npmtest/node_modules/node-sass/vendor' }

> uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall /var/www/npmtest/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
> node lib/post_install.js


> node-sass@4.9.0 postinstall /var/www/npmtest/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: /usr/bin/node /var/www/npmtest/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ '/usr/bin/node',
gyp verb cli   '/var/www/npmtest/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
gyp info using node@8.10.0 | linux | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python2 /usr/bin/python2
gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python2 -c "import platform; print(platform.python_version());"` returned: "2.7.15rc1\n"
gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 8.10.0
gyp verb command install [ '8.10.0' ]
gyp verb install input version string "8.10.0"
gyp verb install installing version: 8.10.0
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
gyp verb install version is good
gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 8.10.0
gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /var/www/npmtest/node_modules/node-sass/build
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/npmtest/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-20-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/var/www/npmtest/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /var/www/npmtest/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v8.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.9.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.9.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/roge/.npm/_logs/2018-05-18T13_53_01_126Z-debug.log
```

7. As i still could not find a solution for the errors, i tried to execute `sudo npm run dev` (and without sudo) what didn't work off course

result:

```
> @ dev /var/www/npmtest
> npm run development


> @ development /var/www/npmtest
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/var/www/npmtest/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at requireConfig (/var/www/npmtest/node_modules/webpack/bin/convert-argv.js:97:18)
    at /var/www/npmtest/node_modules/webpack/bin/convert-argv.js:104:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (/var/www/npmtest/node_modules/webpack/bin/convert-argv.js:102:15)
    at yargs.parse (/var/www/npmtest/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:171:41)
    at Object.Yargs.self.parse (/var/www/npmtest/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:533:18)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/roge/.npm/_logs/2018-05-18T14_01_02_924Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/roge/.npm/_logs/2018-05-18T14_01_02_953Z-debug.log
```

After Google a few hours and trying:
 https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/533 and https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1072 and few more i have no idea where to continue.

For some magic reason is `npm run dev` working in one of my projects. Its the same Laravel version and i have really no idea what i did else there than in the (multiple) new projects i tried to get working...

Did i forget something or something wrong? Hope that someone can help me! Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the same problem

`sudo apt-get install libpng-dev`

`npm install -g pngquant-bin`

Comment: Thanks i also already found the solution. Just `sudo apt-get install libpng-dev` reached out in my case ;)